# Facebook app and activeX

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer

Just to be on the safe side before starting to code: Are there any problems with embedding activeX in FB app?
10xs,
Nahum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your FB app won't work on any browser except IE (I think there might be extensions for other browsers that might let you run ActiveX controls).  If you're okay with that limitation, it should work, since it will be running as an iframe.